# Enabling WCF Tracing through user code

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, trace

I have a WCF service, provided by a partner team, that I host in IIS.
This service, in turn, calls a dll I provide.

Currently, the trace output tells me when the service receives a message, when it crosses the Activity Boundary to my dll, when my dll returns, and when the response message is sent.
From everything I've read, the trace *should* be telling me every method call from end to end, including what's going on in my own code.

The trace source is configured like so:

```
       <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing"  propagateActivity="true">
           <listeners>
               <add name="myListener" />
           </listeners>
       </source>
```

while the listener is configured like this:

```
    <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logs\TraceLogs.svclog" />
```

Is it as simple as a configuration change, or do I need to add a custom trace viewer that I write to, explicitly, for events in my code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Pretty sure that trace listener will only write traces for `System.ServiceModel`.  My guess would be you add another `<source>` specifying your dll and then you're good to go as long as your dll writes traces.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to: Disable/Enable WCF tracing in C# application code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023567/how-to-disable-enable-wcf-tracing-in-c-sharp-application-code)

Answer (score 0):

Here's documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993.aspx

I think all you need to do is configure another `<source>` for your assembly.  And as along as your dll is writing to trace it should work.